# Kivy on_drop_file event stops working after building a pyinstaller exe with --windowed flag

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I have a kivy app which uses on_dop_file event for dragging and dropping video files into the app. The event works fine normally but when I create a pyinstaller build of the app using `---windowed` option, the event stops working. Without `--windowed` mode it works fine as well. This is my implementation.

```
class MyApp(App):
    def _init_(self, **kwargs):
        super()._init_(**kwargs)
        
       
    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_drop_file=self.on_drop_file)
        root_widget = MainWidget()
        return root_widget

    def on_drop_file(self, window, file_path, x, y):
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            abs_path = sys.argv
            
        else:
           abs_path = [file_path.decode('utf-8')]
           
        for fpath in abs_path:
            if fpath.endswith('.mp4') or fpath.endswith('.MP4'):
                self.upload_video("drag",fpath)
```

Is there any work-around for this. any help would be appreciated. Thank You.